# How to select items in date range in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

How can I select all items within a given date range?

SELECT * FROM GameScores where createdAt >= start_date && createAt <=end_date

I want to make a query like this. Do I need to crate a global secondary index or not?

I've tried this

```
public void getItemsByDate(Date start, Date end) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    String stringStart = df.format(start);
    String stringEnd = df.format(end);

    ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec();
    scanSpec.withFilterExpression("CreatedAt BETWEEN :from AND :to")
            .withValueMap(
                    new ValueMap()
                            .withString(":from", stringStart)
                            .withString(":to", stringEnd));

    ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> items = null;
    items = gamesScoresTable.scan(scanSpec);
}
```

But it doesn't work, I'm getting less results than expected.

Comment: What does your key structure look like, what does your data look like? Based on this information all we can say is: it depends.

Comment: I don't know how the java sdk works, but you're doing a scan so it's likely the results will be paginated, so that might explain why you're getting fewer than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your questions, but to suggest any real solution, I would need to see the general shape of your data, as well as what your GameScore's primary key is.

#### TLDR;

Setup your table so that you can retrieve data with queries, rather than scans and filters, and then create indexes to support lesser used access patterns and improve querying flexibility. Because of how fast reads are when providing the full (or, although not as fast, partial) primary key, i.e. using queries, DynamoDB is optimal when table structure is driven by the application's access patterns.

When designing your tables, keep in mind [NoSQL design best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html), as well as [best practices for querying and scanning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html) and it will pay dividends in the long run.

#### Explanations

##### Question 1

*How can I select all items within a given date range?*

To answer this, I'd like to break that question down a little more. Let's start with: *How can I select all items?*

This, you have already accomplished. A scan is a great way to retrieve all items in your table, and unless you have all your items within one partition, it is the *only way* to retrieve all the items in your table. Scans can be helpful when you have to access data by unknown keys.

Scans, however, have limitations, and as your table grows in size they'll cost you in both performance and dollars. A single scan can only retrieve a maximum of 1MB of data, of a single partition, and is capped at that partition's read capacity.  When a scan tops out at either limitation, consecutive scans will happen sequentially. Meaning a scan on a large table could take multiple round trips.

On top of that, with scans you consume read capacity based on the size of the item, no matter how much (or little) data is returned. If you only request a small amount of attributes in your ProjectionExpression, and your FilterExpression eliminates 90% of the items in your table, you still paid to read the entire table.

You can optimize performance of scans using *Parallel Scans*, but if you require an entire table scan for an access pattern that happens frequently for your application, you should consider restructuring your table. [More about scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html).

Let's now look at: *How can I select all items, based on some criteria?*

The ideal way to accomplish retrieving data based on some criteria (in your case `SELECT * FROM GameScores where createdAt >= start_date && createAt <=end_date`) would be to query the base table (or index). To do so, per the documentation:

> You must provide the name of the partition key attribute and a single value for that attribute. Query returns all items with that partition key value.

Like the documentation says, querying a partition will return all of its values. If your GameScores table has a partition key of GameName, then a query for GameName = PacMan will return all Items with that partition key. Other GameName partitions, however, will not be captured in this query.

If you need more depth in your query:

> Optionally, you can provide a sort key attribute and use a comparison operator to refine the search results.

Here's a [list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.KeyConditionExpressions) of all the possible comparison operators you can use with your sort key. This is where you can leverage a `between` comparison operator in the KeyConditionExpression of your query operation. Something like: `GameName = PacMan AND createdAt BETWEEN time1 AND time2` will work, ***if createdAt is the sort key of the table or index that you are querying.***

If it is not the sort key, you might have the answer to your second question.

##### Question 2

*Do I need to create a Global Secondary Index?*

Let's start with: *Do I need to create an index?*

If your base table data structure does not fit some amount of access patterns for your application, you might need to. However, in DynamoDB, the denormalization of data also support more access patterns. I would recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6yqfmXiZTlM) on how to structure your data.

Moving onto: *Do I need to create a GSI?*

GSIs do not support strong read consistency, so if you need that, you'll need to go with a Local Secondary Index (LSI). However, if you've already created your base table, you won't be able to create an LSI. Another difference between the two is the primary key: a GSI can have a different partition and sort key as the base table, while an LSI will only be able to differ in sort key. [More about indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html).